# python script to activate a conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda

```
def activate_conda_environment(env_name):
    subprocess.run(['conda', 'activate', env_name], shell=True, executable="/bin/bash", check=True)

def deactivate_conda_environment():
    subprocess.run(['conda', 'deactivate'], shell=True, executable="/bin/bash", check=True)
```

i am getting this error again and again

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

Comment: Where, exactly, are you getting that error?  You showed us some python functions, but you didn't show an actual **call** to those functions.  Please update the question and add the full error message traceback.

Comment: And, did you actually do `conda init SHELL_NAME` as the error says?

Comment: i did the conda init shell name as the error says, i got this error on the terminal and the call of the function is "activate_conda_environment(environment_name)"

Comment: ...no change     /home/thanos/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
no change     /home/thanos/.bashrc
No action taken.

Comment: @JohnGordon i found out what the problem was  def activate_conda_environment(env_name):
    subprocess.run(['/home/thanos/anaconda3/bin/conda run ', '/home/thanos/anaconda3/bin/activate', env_name], shell=True)

def deactivate_conda_environment():
    subprocess.run(['/home/thanos/anaconda3/bin/conda run', '/home/thanos/anaconda3/bin/deactivate'], shell=True)

activate_conda_environment('fastqc')

subprocess.run(['fastqc', '/home/thanos/genome_assembly/nanopore_data.fastq'])

deactivate_conda_environment()    i should write the full path to the conda commands and "run"

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify. Code is unreadable in comments. [Edit] your question instead.

Comment: i am sorry , i am really new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Have you ran `conda init` yet? Perhaps that's what the error is warning you about.

Comment: This is not an answer.  But now this question is marked as "answered"...